# Get Date from day of year in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with the following information;

```
Stock Code     Day of Year
5102560           170
5102600           167
5102617           163
5102154           164
```

I want to be able to return the date from the day of year number. 
Is there an excel function that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work
`=DATE(2004,1,your_value)`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `=DATE(2014,1,1)+[day of year]-1`. The first part is the starting date, the second your day of year number, and the -1 is required to calculate the proper date since 01/01/2014 is the first day of the year.